# Matlab function filter in c

Tags: c, matlab, filter

I want to write the c code for the matlab filter but I don't obtain the same result; the first members are correct but after, not. I don't know what's wrong.

```
void convolve(const double b[], size_t b_Len,
          const double h[], size_t h_Len,
          double result[],
          const double a[])
{
int i,j;
result[0]=b[0]*h[0];
for (i=1;i<h_Len+1;i++)
{
    result[i]=0;
    for (j=0;j<i+1;j++)
        result[i]=result[i]+b[j]*h[i-j];
    for (j=0;j<i;j++)
        result[i]=result[i]-a[j+1]*result[i-j-1];
}
```

Comment: You need to tell us 1) what you put into the function 2) what you got out of the function 3) what you expected to get out of the function 4) why you expected that output, i.e. what is a `convolve` function intended to calculate.

Comment: It appears the user is trying to emulate the behaviour of the Matlab [`filter`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html) function.

Comment: @user3386109 according to the filter instruction in matlab , y=filter(b,a,x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "coef_b.h"
extern  double x[];

#define NN 48
#define MM 13
float a=1;
double result [NN];

void convolve(const real64_T b[], 
          const double x[], 
          double result[],
          const float a)
{
FILE *f;
int i,j,l,k;
double temp[96]={0};

for(i=0;i<48;i++)
    temp[48+i]=x[i];

    for(j=48;j<96;j++)
{
    for(l=0;l<13;l++)
        result[j-48]=result[j-48]+temp[j-l]*b[l];   
}

f =fopen("super_result.dat","w");
    for (k = 0; k<48; k++)
    {
        fprintf(f,"%lf\n",result[k]);
    }
    fclose(f);
    return;
}


 int main(void)
 {
 convolve(B,
       x,
       result,
       a);

  return 0;
}
```